# How to set array of step values

Tags: nouislider

For example. We have range of clothes size 64,76,82,95, and We want what user can choose only  these values.
Can We set step by array?

```
step: [64,76,82,95]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using the snap option. Have a look at [snapping between steps](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/) in the documentation.